# Testing accuracy always more than 99%

Tags: theano, keras, lstm, language-model

I am trying to implement a language model using LSTMs in theano/keras. My network runs fine and I also see that the training loss decreases but the testing accuracy is always above 99% even if I don not train my network for long. 
I have used word2vec vectors and embedded the weights in the Embedding layer. My network looks like:

```
model = Graph()  
model.add_input(name='input', input_shape=(n_train,), dtype=int)  
model.add_node(Embedding(output_dim=rnn_dim, input_dim=n_symbols, weights=[embedding_weights]),name = 'embedding',input='input')  
model.add_node(LSTM(output_dim=dense_dim,input_dim=rnn_dim), name='forward', input='embedding')  
model.add_node(Dropout(0.5), name='dropout', input='forward')  
model.add_node(Dense(output_size, activation='softmax'), name='softmax', input='dropout')  
model.add_output(name='output', input='softmax')  

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.99, nesterov=True)  
model.compile(sgd, loss={'output': 'categorical_crossentropy'})  
print("Train...")  
model.fit({'input': X_train,'output': y_train},
      batch_size=128,
      nb_epoch=1,verbose=1)
```

My training and testing array shapes are:
X_train shape: (100000, 18)
X_test shape: (10000, 18)
y_train shape: (100000, 998)
y_test shape: (10000, 998)

where there are 100000 training and 10000 testing sentences and each sentence contains 18 words. The number of classes for output is 998.

Can anyone suggest why I might not be getting a genuine testing error?

Comment: Are your classes balanced or there is a class (or classes) which dominates other?

Comment: Is this true even for fake data?  Is your training accuracy also >99%?  How do you calculate training/test accuracy?